# How to get contentData and ContentFileName for FeedComment Post

Tags: apex, soql

Can anyone tell me how to get the contentData and contentFileName for FeedComment ?
I can get same for FeedItem using below query.

```
[select Id,RelatedRecordId,Type,Body,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.FirstName,
 CreatedBy.LastName,Title,LinkUrl,ContentData,ContentFileName 
 From FeedItem]
```

But there is no contentData,ContentFileName field in FeedComment Class.
Please help me how can I  get for FeedComment?

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `FeedComment` behaves a little bit different from `FeedItem`.

`RelatedRecordId` on `FeedComment` https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm

refers to the `ContentVersion` object https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm#sforce_api_objects_contentversion

Which looks like it has the data you're looking for.

The `Title` field contains the filename, and the `FileExtension` field contains the extension.

Comment: I have seen those page.I need a contentFileName..Where I can get that?

Comment: That'll be in the Title field, and the extension will be in the FileExtension field.

Answer (score -1):

You can see fields name in documentation - https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm